# Как выделить, сохранить выделение, и восстановить его

Tags: javascript, angularjs, text

Есть такой html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="textCtrl.text"></div>
```

Это простой `<div>` контейнер, в котором расположен html-текст.

- Цепочка действий которую мне нужно реализовать:

  1. Пользователь выделяет текст мышкой
  2. Нажимает правую кнопку, и в контекстном меню(уже реализовано) выбирает `Mark`
  3. Я сохраняю в БД позицию выделения, и меняю цвет фона под этим выделением
  4. Обновляю страницу
  5. Получаю с БД позицию выделения и восстанавливаю его после загрузки страницы

Проблема у меня начинается с пункта #3, я не пойму как мне сохранить позицию выделения что бы потом выделить в точном месте еще раз этот текст, после обновления страницы например, или если я захочу использовать этот `div` в другом месте(всплывающее окно например).

Каким то может быть образом можно получить `offset` от начала этого div'а и потом как то восстановить это выделение по этому оффсету, или как это грамотно сделать?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/range-textrange-selection Вот здесь можете посмотреть.